# an asp.net routing issue

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, url-routing

my route implementation on Global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.intRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

void intRoutes(RouteCollection Rts)
        {
            Rts.MapPageRoute("search", "{language}/{page}", "~/search.aspx");
            Rts.MapPageRoute("category", "{language}/{name}/{no}/{categoryname}", "~/category.aspx");
            Rts.MapPageRoute("product", "{language}/{name}/{no}/{productname}", "~/product.aspx");
        }
```

the problem is; if i use **product** routing on a hyperlink, like as follows;

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyProduct" 
        NavigateUrl='<%#HttpUtility.UrlDecode(((Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler).GetRouteUrl("product", new{ language=getUIFromHelper(),name=getNameFromHelper(),no=Eval("code"),productname=getProductNameFromHelper(Eval("name"))})) %>' runat="server" Text="something" />
```

everything goes fine, the link is written as expected like

```
/en/products/06.008.001.150.0510/davis-fish-seeker-green
```

but when i click that link the **category.aspx** page runs insted of product.aspx.

am i missing out something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, how can the router tell which one you want? They both have four placeholders with no fixed directories. There is no way to tell which one was intended.

You'll need to do something like add a fixed directory so that it's possible to distinguish between the two:

```
Rts.MapPageRoute(..., "{language}/Category/{no}/{categoryname}", ...
Rts.MapPageRoute(..., "{language}/Product/{no}/{productname}", ...
```

Comment: yes Jonathan ,i've noticed that, both routes have same structure.
i should change one of them...
thanks for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

i've added the additional virtual folder both category and product routes which are **/c/** and **/p/**

```
void intRoutes(RouteCollection Rts)
        {
            Rts.MapPageRoute("search", "{language}/{page}", "~/search.aspx");
            Rts.MapPageRoute("category", "{language}/c/{name}/{no}/{categoryname}", "~/category.aspx");
            Rts.MapPageRoute("product", "{language}/p/{name}/{no}/{productname}", "~/product.aspx");
        }
```

and now, the router can distinguish which one is wanted..